# Laravel 5.2: Entrust: Call to undefined method attachPermission

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to attach permission if not present and got error after run db seed -

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;
use App\User;

class AttachRolesAndPermissionsToUsers extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $admin = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();
        $moderator = Role::where('name', 'moderator')->first();

        $createPost = Permission::where('name', 'create-post')->first();
        $editUser = Permission::where('name', 'edit-user')->first();


        // attach role
        $adminUser = User::where('email', 'a@gmail.com')->first();
        if(!$adminUser->hasRole('admin')) {
            $adminUser->attachRole($admin);
        }

        $moderatorUser = User::where('email', 'b@gmail.com')->first();
        if(!$moderatorUser->hasRole('moderator')) {
            $moderatorUser->attachRole($moderator);
        }

        // attach Permission
        if(!$adminUser->can(['create-post', 'edit-user'])) {
            $adminUser->attachPermissions([$createPost, $editUser]);
        }

        if(!$moderatorUser->can('create-post')) {
            $moderatorUser->attachPermission($createPost);
        }
    }
}
```

[BadMethodCallException] Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attachPermission()

Comment: check in your User model that attachPermission() method is exist.

Comment: No it's not, attachPermission shouldn't suppose to be in user model, it should come along with entrust package. Like I am using can, hasRole method without having them on user model

Comment: I guess i am doing a wrong that is i should attach permission to role not with user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was wrong implementation, permission need to be attach with Role not with user.

```
$admin->attachPermissions([$createPost, $editUser]);
$moderator->attachPermission($createPost);
```

Where `$admin` and `$moderator` is role object.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
$adminUser->perms()->sync([$createPost->id, $editUser->id]);
```

and let see how it goes.

Comment: I think i am doing a wrong implementation, i should attach permission to roles not with user. Anyway i will get back to you.